# Incomprehensible object reassignment in javascript

Tags: javascript, game-engine

I've been looking at the examples of this game engine and I really don't understand why it reassigns the object, I code in java and I'm learning javascript, it may be a concept error.

example
https://blacksmith2d.io/Docs/Examples/Arcade-Physics/CollisionEvents

onassetsLoaded() event he is setting object properties and then reassign it again below.

```
this.arcade = arcade;
this.circle = circle;
this.box = box;
```

also i don't understand this part on if statement

```
!this.circle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About these statements:

```
this.arcade = arcade;
this.circle = circle;
this.box = box;
```

Earlier in that block of code, all variables that occur at the right side were defined as *local* variables (local to the method `onAssetsLoaded`):

```
const arcade = ...
const circle = ...
const box = ...
```

So the assignments that have you wondering are in fact copying references from local variables to instance variables (i.e. properties). This is needed to not lose this information once the `onAssetsLoaded` call has completed.

As to this expression:

```
!this.circle
```

The not-operator (`!`) can be used on any expression. It evaluates to `true` when the operand is "falsy". In JavaScript values like `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `""`, `NaN`, are considered "falsy", while all objects are considered "truthy". Here it is used to detect that `this.circle` has not been assigned a proper value, i.e. it would mean that `onAssetsLoaded` had not yet been called, and `this.circle` was still `undefined`.

Comment: using this in javascript means local variable applies globally, is this correct? , I was thinking in java.

Comment: `this` is an object. It can get properties. `this.a = 1` will give a value to a property of the `this` object. If you have also a variable called `a`, then realise that this is *not* a synonym for `this.a`. If that `a` variable is local, and you want to not lose that information after it goes out of scope, then you need to copy it to something that can be accessed from elsewhere, like `this.a`. There is a lot to say about `this`, as it doesn't always act the same way as in Java. Check out the very enlightening [How does the this keyword work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/5459839).

Comment: ok, i'm checking this url , anyways i give your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Java and Javascript are as similar as a Car and a Carpet https://stackoverflow.com/a/245068/1897495 :-). The knowledge that you have acquired in Java cannot be directly transposed.

Unlike in Java, access to objects properties are explicit in Javascript: the use of `this.` is mandatory.
The same goes when calling methods from the same class (you need to use `this.`)

```js
class SomeClass {
   constructor() {
       this.param1 = 42;
   }

   localAndParameter(param1) {
       console.log(this.param1); // prints "42"
       console.log(param1); // prints "666"
   }

   localAndGlobal() {
       console.log(this.param1); // still "42"
       console.log(param1); // prints 123
   }

   callMethods() {
       this.emptyMethod(); // this works
       emptyMethod(); // This would raise an exception if called
       // "emptyMethod" is undefined or something like that
   }

   emptyMethod() {
   }
}

const param1 = 123;
const obj = new SomeClass();
obj.localAndParameter(666);
obj.localAndGlobal();
```

Also the language is dynamic.

Properties can be added to objects at all times, not only when declared/constructed

```js
class SomeClass {
   constructor() {
       // no properties created.
   }

   someMethod() {
       // everything is dynamic! I can create a property here
       this.newProperty = 23;
   }
}

const obj = new SomeClass()
console.log(obj.newProperty); // prints "undefined"
obj.someMethod();
console.log(obj.newProperty); // prints "23"
```

Comment: so basically if he doesn't use this when he was adding these properties , that's why is he reassignment the object?

Comment: I think the confusion of the OP just comes from not understanding than `this.something` and `something` are not the same in Javascript (which is the case in Java)

Comment: yes, you are correct , i was thinking in java , that's why i don't understand this concept